# What is Proguard's obfuscated local variable naming convention?

Tags: java, proguard, local-variables

Proguard obfuscates local variables, unless told otherwise. From the manual:

> ProGuard's obfuscation step **does** remove the original names entirely, unless you explicitly keep the LocalVariableTable or LocalVariableTypeTable attributes.

I am in possession of both the source code and the obfuscation map for an app, however there is no information I can see relating to the mapping for local variable names. I'm wanting to plug in a debugging agent to print out some variable names for some methods in a distribution of the app (I've made the agent using javassist), however this is not an easy task without knowing the variable names.

It's not the source code variable name, and my IDE's java decompiler says the variable's names are "var0", "var1" which are also not correct (and I suspect are just placeholders).

Comment: It means what it says. The class files contain *no local variable names*, so how could it possibly give you a map? (The names you see were made up by your decompiler)

Comment: I guess a followup question then would be, what would javaassist-injected source code look like that would print out those variables' values?

Comment: Never mind, the answer to that follow up question was "rtfm"... http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/tutorial/tutorial2.html - the variable names $1, $2 etc can be used to print out method parameters.